# kubectl diff on PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, kubernetes, diff

`kubectl` can diff configuration ([blog](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/01/14/apiserver-dry-run-and-kubectl-diff/), [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#diff)).

On Linux, this works fine (WSL, Ubuntu 18, bash). It gives me sensible output similar to the following.

```
$ kubectl diff --filename some-resources.yaml
diff -u -N /tmp/LIVE-022965340/apps.v1.Deployment.… /tmp/MERGED-396067851/apps.v1.Deployment.…
--- /tmp/LIVE-022965340/apps.v1.Deployment.…      2020-07-20 17:06:21.444811700 +0200
+++ /tmp/MERGED-396067851/apps.v1.Deployment.…    2020-07-20 17:06:21.470315500 +0200
@@ -6,7 +6,7 @@
     kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
       {"apiVersion":"apps/v1",…
   creationTimestamp: "2020-07-16T15:13:03Z"
-  generation: 1
+  generation: 2
   name: …
   namespace: …
   resourceVersion: "32827467"
@@ -121,7 +121,7 @@
         - chown www-data:www-data /files/ -R;chmod -R 755 /files/; chmod -R g+ws /files/
         command:
         - /bin/bash
-        - -c
+        - -cv
         image: …
         imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
         name: init-sites-volume
```

On PowerShell, `kubectl diff` fails (PowerShell 7, Windows 10).

```
PS > kubectl diff --filename some-resources.yaml
error: failed to run "diff": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

It seems that either `kubectl` can't find an executable named `diff`, or it trips up over `diff` being an alias for `Compare-Object`, which of course has very different syntax than Linux' `diff`.

Is it possible to get `kubectl diff` to work on PowerShell? If so, which diff-tool should I install and what should `$env:KUBECTL_EXTERNAL_DIFF=…` be set to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by installing [DiffUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm). The `kubectl diff` is using the Unix `diff` program so Windows will need some help with this. Simply:

- Install the DiffUtils
- Make sure the bin folder is mapped in your Win10 PATH variable (should be done automatically)
- Restart the machine

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Yep, that worked. `scoop install diffutils` fixed it, no changes to PATH or restarts necessary. Thanks!